# this inside react class component works differently

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and if I try to get access to `openm2()` using `this.openm2()` in `openm` method then I got error

> "Cannot read property 'openm2' of undefined"

```
class Car extends React.Component {
  openm2() {
    return "Hello from openm2";
  }

  openm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.openm2(); Here I get error

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          {this.props.type.map((item, index) => {
            return <p key={index}>{item}</p>;
          })}
        </h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.openm}>
          <input type="text" name="type" />
          <button>Remo all</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56/) may help (pun intended). Probably want to use bind in constructor

Comment: like @HMR pointed out, you may bind your methods in constructor, or you may simply define your methods slightly different, namely `openm = (e) => { ...` (Public Class Fields Syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `openm` function to arrow function, which binds `this` to function automatically.

```
openm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.openm2(); Here I get error
}
```

Or, you can bind `this` like,

```
<form onSubmit={this.openm.bind(this)}>
```

Or, you can bind `this` in constructor

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.openm = this.openm.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, please can you explain what happens behind the scenes with this in React. It turns out that this in React works a bit differently than in vanilla JS Right?

Comment: @Dickens No it doesn't

Comment: You can read more about `this` here - https://medium.com/byte-sized-react/what-is-this-in-react-25c62c31480

Comment: Check this - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/

Comment: Or you could make it a functional component and avoid `this` altogether :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the current `this` reference, so you can use the arrow function for this. please check below code

```
class Car extends React.Component {
  openm2 = () => {
    return "Hello from openm2";
  }

  openm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.openm2();     
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          {this.props.type.map((item, index) => {
            return <p key={index}>{item}</p>;
          })}
        </h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.openm}>
          <input type="text" name="type" />
          <button>Remo all</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```